# How to update div opened in a dialog widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is my setup:

```
<td>
    <div style="width:100px;height:30px; background:#009814; border:medium solid; border-color:#fff" onclick="showPopup(this)"> </div>
    <div style="display:none" title="Indicators"><input type="checkbox"/> Indicators go here </div>
</td>
```

```js
function showPopup(elem) {
    var el = $(elem);
    var div = $(el.siblings()[0]);
    var populDiv = div.show();
    var dialog = populDiv.dialog({
        closeOnEscape: true,
        beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
            //update div somehow
        }
    });
}
```

I am opening a dialog with a hidden div as it's content and the div is removed form the `td` and placed in the dialog. My question is how do I put it back keeping the checkbox checked/unchecked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as little tricky, as you need to clone original div, show it, and before closing dialog replace it with dialog contents, and also hide it again.

```
function showPopup(elem) {
    var orig = $($(elem).siblings()[0]);
    var populDiv = $('<div>').append(orig.clone().show());
    var dialog = populDiv.dialog({
        closeOnEscape: true,
        beforeClose: function(event, ui) {
            orig.replaceWith(populDiv.children().eq(0).hide());
        }
    });
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/46Bn7Y1nRelghNPKMDkz?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to remove the hidden element and move it to the dialog, on close re-add the element at its former position:

```
function showPopup(elem) {
  // retrieve the hidden element after the clicked div
  var el = $($(elem).siblings()[0]);
  // append it to the #dialog container, show the content and display the dialog()
  var dialog = $('#dialog').html('').append(el.show()).dialog({
    closeOnEscape: true,
    beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
        // hide the element again and re-add it behind the clickable element
        el.hide().insertAfter($(elem));
    }
  });
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/r6xu01wx/1/